# A question to Flash experts from a beginner: the flash object within a web page

Tags: flash

**Here's my explanation of the question:**

From JavaScript, you need to get a reference to the Flash Player object. There are two basic Flash Player versions that run in the browser: ActiveX and the plug-in version. The ActiveX version runs natively in Internet Explorer, while the plug-in version is used by the rest of the browsers.

The ActiveX player is controlled by the *object* tag in an HTML page, and you can retrieve a JavaScript reference using window. objectId where objectId is the value of the id attribute of the *object* tag. For example, if the *object* tag's id attribute is example, then the reference to the ActiveX player would be window.example.

The plug-in player is controlled by the *embed* tag in an HTML page, and you can retrieve a JavaScript reference by using window.document. embedName, where embedName is the value of the name attribute of the *embed* tag. For example, if the *embed* tag's name attribute is example, then the reference to the plug-in player would be window.document.example.

**And here's the question itself:**

Why does the Flash Player Object exist as a *window* property when embeded via the *object* tag, while, when embeded via the *embed* tag, it exists in the *window.document* property? And what is the most modern way of getting the Flash Player Object from within a web page?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is embedded in the question itself. IE uses `object` tags and hence SWF is a `window` object when embedded with `object` tags. Rest of the world uses `embed` tags and hence SWF is a property of the `window.document` for them.

Comment: Excuse me, but it doesn't simply work in my IE 6 when I try to get the object like so: var o = window.flashId; But when I get the object like so: var o = window[flashId]; or like so: var o = document[flashId]; - it works in my IE 6. So, how on earth do people get the object??? How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Today I got a funny things. I use the common way to embed a flash in my [blog](http://blog.jmsliu.com/61/call-actionscript-functions-by-javascript.html).

```
<object id="flashObject" width="290" height="100" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
    <param name="movie" value="javascriptcallflash.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed name="flashObject" width="100%" height="100%" wmode="transparent" allowScriptAccess="always" width="290" height="100" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="javascriptcallflash.swf"/>
</object>
```

And I also use the common way to get the flash reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getFlashMovie(movieName) {   
        var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
        return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];  
    }
    function CallFlashFun() {
        var textarea = document.getElementById("jsMsg")
        var flashObj = getFlashMovie("flashObject");
        flashObj.asFunction(textarea.value);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that after I publish the post. It doesn't work. So I have try to replace `window[movieName]` to `window.document[movieName].` Then it works. It's very weird.

What's the different between window[movieName], document[movieName], and window.document[movieName]?

Answer (score 0):

[swfobject.js](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) still does this most reliably. So much so that it's been adopted by Adobe as the default embedding script.